# Rails 3: Fileupload without generating tempfile

Tags: file-upload, ruby-on-rails-3

I am looking for a way to upload a file to Rails 3 app, but without generating a temp file. Googling the issue gave me some insight in how the file upload works. As I understand Rails creates a temp file when the file size is larger than 20kb. Is there a way to change this limit and avoid the temp file generation?

Another solution I was looking in was creating a Rack App and so avoid the file generation, however, didn't work either. Same with a Sinatra app.

Btw. yes it is mandatory that the file is not saved and only kept in memory for security reasons.

Thanks

Comment: Have you managed to find an answer? I am also interested.

Comment: Actually no. I tracked down the creation in Rack, but I wasn't able to prevent it. Since this problem was crucial and time was limited, we used JBoss Netty.

Comment: I am also facing same problem. Did you skipped Rails application development and implemented the application in JBoss Netty or used Both?.

Answer (score 0):

Check out https://github.com/jnicklas/carrierwave I don't think it uses a tempfile when saving to disk (or other storage locations)

Answer (score 0):

**MatthewFord**, it is...

```
self.class.new({:tempfile => new_path, :content_type => content_type})
```